# Two arbitary products are disjoint if for _at least_ one coordinate $j_0$ it holds that $U_{j_0} \cap V_{j_0} = \emptyset$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

When proving that the product $X = \prod_{j \in J} X_j$ of Hausdorff spaces $X_j$ is Hausdorff we resort to the fact that two products $$\prod_{j \in J} U_j \text{ and } \prod_{j \in J} V_j$$ are disjoint if for *at least* one coordinate $j_0$ it holds that $U_{j_0} \cap V_{j_0} = \emptyset$. I'm not quite getting my head around this. I know that if they're disjoint in $j_0$, then if $x \in \left( \prod_{j \in J} U_j \cap\prod_{j \in J} V_j\right)$ I should have that $x \in \prod_{j \in J} U_j$ and that $x \in \prod_{j \in J} V_j$ and so $x_{j_0} \in U_{j_0}$ and $x_{j_0} \in V_{j_0}$ which is a contradictory result, but is there a "direct" way to see this?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the products for a second.
This follows from a more general result on sets.

**Lemma** let $A, B\subseteq S$, and $f: S\to T$ a function.
If $f(A)\cap f(B)$ is empty, so is $A\cap B$.

And this follows from $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$, which you can prove by monotonicity of the image.

Now apply this lemma to the projection $\pi_{j_0}: \prod_j X_j \to X_{j_0}$, and you should see why what you wrote is a sufficient criterion for disjointness of these „boxes“